# Output Powershell Domain Search on separate excel sheets

Tags: powershell

I'm executing a `Get-ADComputer` and trying to iterate through a loop that pulls computer names from individual rooms. I'm trying to output each room to a different Excel sheet.

I'm running PowerShell Version 5:

```
$results = for($room=102; $room -le 110; $room++) {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $oubase -Properties Name, Description -Filter * |
        Where-Object {$_.description -clike "*RM $Room"}
}

$results | 
    Select-Object Name, Description |
        Export-CSV '\\Desktop\Room_Hosts.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

What do I need to do to fix the Excel sheet output?

Comment: You will need to create an Excel COM object and access it's properties from that object to manipulate Excel. Take a look at this on TechNet: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035 and Google PSExcel. RamblingCookie Monster has a module called PSExcel that might take out some of the grunt work for you

Answer (score 1):

Your post says you want an Excel sheet, but your code is outputting to a CSV. You cannot add a second sheet to a CSV. You can export different CSV files per computer object.

```
$results = for($room=102; $room -le 110; $room++) {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $oubase -Properties Name, Description -Filter * |
        Where-Object {$_.description -clike "*RM $Room"}
}

$results | 
    Select-Object Name, Description | Foreach-Object {
        $_ | Export-CSV -Path ("\\Desktop\{0}.csv" -f $_.Name) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

If the problem is getting the domain name, you can add some code to your `Select-Object` command.

```
$results = for($room=102; $room -le 110; $room++) {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $oubase -Properties Name,Description,DNSHostName -Filter * |
        Where-Object {$_.description -clike "*RM $Room"}
}

$results | 
    Select-Object Name,Description,@{n='Domain';e={$_.DNSHostName -Replace $("{0}." -f $_.Name}} |
        Export-CSV '\\Desktop\Room_Hosts.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

**Explanation For Retrieving Computer Object's Domain:**

The `DNSHostName` property contains the FQDN of the computer object. So you only need to remove the host name part of that string. Here, we simply replace the hostname and the following `.` character with nothing. Hostname is retrieved from the `Name` property of the computer object. The `-f` operator is used to simply append the `.` character to the name. The `Select-Object` uses a hash table to calculate the domain value and store it in a property called Domain.

Alternatively, you can apply the same concepts from above for getting the domain name but use the CanonicalName of the computer object with the `-Split` operator.

```
$results = for($room=102; $room -le 110; $room++) {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $oubase -Properties Name,CanonicalName,Description -Filter * |
        Where-Object {$_.description -clike "*RM $Room"}
}

$results | 
    Select-Object Name,Description,@{n='Domain';e={($_.CanonicalName -Split "/")[0]}} |
        Export-CSV '\\Desktop\Room_Hosts.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```